# I am trying to make a script that will constantly check if a player has a gamepass, and if not, set the players walkspeed to 0

Tags: lua, roblox

The script keeps returning false even after I purchase the gamepass. It keeps telling me to purchase it over and over, and it never says "you already own this gamepass". I need help to figure out what is causing this.

```lua
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local MPS = game.MarketplaceService
local Humanoid = Player.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 0
Humanoid.JumpPower = 0
while wait(3) do
    if MPS:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(Player.UserId, 48752534) then -- Checks if player has walk
gamepass
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 18.5
        print("A")
    else
        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = 0
        MPS:PromptGamePassPurchase(Player, 48752534)
        print("B")
    end
end
```

Comment: did you implement the [MarketplaceService.ProcessReceipt](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/callback/MarketplaceService/ProcessReceipt) callback?

Comment: @Kylaaa No. How would I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement the processreceipt callback under your script.

```
-- The core 'ProcessReceipt' callback function
local function processReceipt(receiptInfo)
 
    -- Determine if the product was already granted by checking the data store  
    local playerProductKey = receiptInfo.PlayerId .. "_" .. receiptInfo.PurchaseId
 
    local success, isPurchaseRecorded = pcall(function()
        return purchaseHistoryStore:UpdateAsync(playerProductKey, function(alreadyPurchased)
            if alreadyPurchased then
                return true
            end
 
            -- Find the player who made the purchase in the server
            local player = Players:GetPlayerByUserId(receiptInfo.PlayerId)
            if not player then
                -- The player probably left the game
                -- If they come back, the callback will be called again
                return nil
            end
 
            local handler = productFunctions[receiptInfo.ProductId]
 
            local success, result = pcall(handler, receiptInfo, player)
            -- If granting the product failed, do NOT record the purchase in datastores.
            if not success or not result then
                error("Failed to process a product purchase for ProductId:", receiptInfo.ProductId, " Player:", player)
                return nil
            end
 
            -- Record the transcation in purchaseHistoryStore.
            return true
        end)
    end)
 
    if not success then
        error("Failed to process receipt due to data store error.")
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet
    elseif isPurchaseRecorded == nil then
        -- Didn't update the value in data store.
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.NotProcessedYet
    else    
        -- IMPORTANT: Tell Roblox that the game successfully handled the purchase
        return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted
    end
end
 
-- Set the callback; this can only be done once by one script on the server! 
MarketplaceService.ProcessReceipt = processReceipt
`
```

Comment: This is a great answer since it utilizes the DataStore for persistent storage, but for clarity, 
could you explain what are the `purchaseHistoryStore` and the `productFunctions[receiptInfo.ProductId]`? Since they aren't part of the original question.